# vsftpd file uploading fail

Tags: linux, ftp

I have a Lenny server with vsftpd as ftp server.
I have to upload a lot of jgps files, each named like this:

05-09-2010-01.jpg
05-09-2010-02.jpg
....

until

05-09-2010-40.jpg

My problem is that the file "05-09-2010-17.jpg" (seventeen) fails! if I try to upload manually  fails too. The only way is rename it, then upload to the remote server.

The client Ubuntu with LVM partitions.

I'm using the command line ftp client (because I use it in a script)

any ideas?!

Comment: Vsftpd.log says

Comment: Put the logging level of vsftp right up to maximum, and then examine the logs again. The man page should tell you how to do this.

Comment: Sun Sep 5 06:15:59 2010 [pid 21124] [elp OK UPLOAD: Client "200.*4", "/public_html/digital/images/05-09-2010-14.jpg", 448208 bytes, 96.75Kbyte/sec Sun Sep 5 06:16:04 2010 [pid 21124] [elpin OK UPLOAD: Client "200.*", "/public_html/digital/images/05-09-2010-15.jpg", 449698 bytes, 87.51Kbyte/sec Sun Sep 5 06:16:09 2010 [pid 21124] [elpin OK UPLOAD: Client "200.x...", "/public_html/digital/images/05-09-2010-16.jpg", 408319 bytes, 91.82Kbyte/sec then nothing.

Comment: Please provide the script that you use to upload the file. What do you mean by "upload manually fails too". What program do you use for manual upload? What message you receive when uploading manually?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is an existing file with that same name in the same directory, and possibly it is owned by a user that vsftpd can't write over.  Also, if I recall correctly, I think you can limit upload size in vsftpd.conf; maybe it is set too low.